# How can c# share the generic implementations of reference types when 'typeof' and 'is' are used?

Tags: c#, generics, clr, cil

As far as I understand, at runtime the CLR implementation creates different machine code (or whatever runtime representation) for the same generic Type with different parameterized valuetypes, but shares the machine code for reference types. This makes sense since reference types are going to take up the same size (the size of a reference).

What I don't understand is how this can work with code that explicitly uses code which depends on the type of T directly through something like typeof(T) or is T. For example, in the class:

```
class TestClass<T> 
{
    public static bool TestAType(Object pObj) { return pObj is T; }
}
```

I don't see how the same implementation for T = List and T = String can allow `TestClass<String>.TestAType("hello")` to be true and `TestClass<List<int>>.TestAType("hello")` to be false.

I'm making the assumption here that the machine code is the same for the compiled generic types, which could of course be false.

Comment: I think you're talking about the JITted machine code, *not* IL.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I think I am

Comment: These are not implemented by machine code instructions, the jitter generates a call to CLR helper functions.  Which know that the type is generic from the type handle.

Comment: Hans Passant. Right, but if the machine code is the same, then isn't the typehandle the same? sure typeof(T) will be implemented with ldtoken T; Call GetTypeFromTypeHandle;, but surely ldtoken will be JITed to the same machine code?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/lewischeng-ms/sscli/blob/adbd6bbad0816f65650a66e1701112a307dc4b09/clr/src/jit64/reader.cpp#L4418) code does it.

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking. It seems rather like asking "how can the function `x => x + x` be compiled *once* but give *different* values when passed 1 and 2?"  How is your question different than that question? Type parameters are called type parameters because they are *parameters*. The runtime knows what they are at the call site! The same as the runtime knows the values of formal parameters at the call site. The call site and the callee site cooperate to know what the necessary parameters are.

Comment: @EricLippert so every generic class has a field which stores the generic parameter types? Where is this field stored? That would work though definitely, since the same machine code would give different outputs as the type at the field would be different depending on the generic type.

Comment: @IllidanS4 This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! If you make an answer I'll mark it as done!

Comment: @Nick: I said absolutely nothing even resembling "every generic class has a field that stores the parameters", so I'm not sure where you got that conclusion from. Rather, I said that the *call site of the genericized method has compile-time information about the type parameters*. Just like the call site of a regular method has runtime information about the values of the arguments and compile-time information about their types.

Comment: @EricLippert I thought your point here was that x => x compiles to the same code, but gives different values for different values of x. Similarly, generic types can be compiled to the same code, but at runtime can be given different values of type parameters, hence giving different behaviours at runtime.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. How you got out of that the idea that there is a *field that stores parameters*, I do not know.  Perhaps you mean something different by "field" or "parameter" than I do. When you call a normal method, are the arguments "fields" in your world view?

Comment: Well presumably in order to get the type parameters into the runtime, storing them in a field is one way of doing that. E.g. in the class you're store the value of generic type parameter. It was just a stretch I guess. But now I think about it, that's actually a bad way of doing it. (static methods don't have any <this> objects which can contain the generic type parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native code generated for each generic instantiation using reference types is indeed the same (having `System.__Canon` as the parameter internally) but that doesn't mean the code should have no access to the original type arguments. The native code can access the metadata via helper functions and retrieve the types.

It would be useful to examine actual native code generated by such a method, but from browsing the SSCLI, it looks like [this](https://github.com/lewischeng-ms/sscli/blob/adbd6bbad0816f65650a66e1701112a307dc4b09/clr/src/jit64/reader.cpp#L4418) function does the job, according to its description:

```
// Given information about how to do a runtime lookup, generate the tree
// for the runtime lookup.
//
// Run-time lookup is required if the enclosing method is shared between instantiations
// and the token refers to formal type parameters whose instantiation is not known
// at compile-time.
```